# How to determine "trendiness" of a time series

Tags: time-series, trend

I'd like to be able to compare two timeseries as to their level of "trendiness" to determine which trends better.
For example, assume two stocks, Google and IBM. Would like to understand approaches to determining which of the two trends better.
I realize that the concept of trend is a bit vague.
If one were to look at charts of two stocks (GOOG and IBM for example) one may visually exhibit smooth trends where it goes up for 20 days with little interruption and then goes down for 30 days with little interruption whereas the other may be very noisy in its movement.
Someone looking at the charts may say the first stock trends better. My question is how to mathematically/statistically determine this.

One approach might be to mark highs and lows that represent at least an N% (say 15) change in prices on both stocks and the one with the fewest N% changes therefore trends better.
Any other ideas? Is there a commonly accepted approach to this in the timeseries community?

Comment: There is already massive focus on trend determination in time series. However, it seems that your "trendiness" is to do with how well the trend captures all of the variability, and so high trendiness is low variability around the trend, and _vice versa_. If so, the recipe is: determine the trend and then quantify the variability around it. Neither is trivial but there is no shortage on advice on either in any time series text.

Comment: Nick, thanks for the information. Will have to to some reading on the subject. When you say "determine the trend" what is it I'm seeking to do here and what will my answer look like? What tests should be run?

Comment: It's not really a matter of tests. It's a matter of finding the right estimation method for your purpose. That might be as simple as moving averages. You might need something else. What you should do can't be specified in a comment!

Comment: Perhaps this may help. I'd say that the main idea here was an echo of a standard idea in time series analysis, namely to think of the data as a combination data  $=$ trend $+$ residual. In this case the definition of trend is very generous, as whatever shows pattern. What is not trivial is precisely how to determine trend, as most of time series analysis is about different ideas on that. But once you determine trend, then you seem to be talking about measuring the variability of the residuals; again how you do it depends on your precise aims.

Comment: As near as I can tell, "trendiness" is a concept that might be captured by *temporal correlation of residuals* (relative to some underlying model). In the simplest case the model asserts the values fluctuate around some constant (such as zero). Long upwards or downwards sequences indicate large positive correlation, while rapid fluctuations above and below the average indicate large negative correlation. I very strongly doubt that statistical theory has neglected to recognize and evaluate "trendiness": the issue here is that the idea is only vaguely expressed in the post. (cc @NickCox)

Answer (score 1):

Nick Cox is correct that "trends" are the subject of a plethora of metrics by technically oriented financial analysts. While these technical trend metrics may be quite intensive methodologically, they tend to be weak or lacking in statistical rigor and motivation otherwise. In other words, they are pretty simple minded heuristics. What they do confirm is that your question is more about qualitative measures of "trendiness." On this topic there are no shortage of opinions.

My preference in trend analysis is to, first, answer the question of the growth rate and whether or not this growth is exponential or greater than exponential. The really interesting trends are the ones showing growth faster than exponential as these imply "bubbles" of some type. Then, over and against the growth rate, the slope or the rate of change in the predictors relative to *Y*, there is the *acceleration* in the slope or the rate of change in the rate of change. This is typically based on the slope of the second difference of *Y* wrt itself. *Acceleration* is also known as the Hessian and is considered one of the "greeks" in quantitative finance. Ron Gallant, in his 1986 *Nonlinear Modeling* book described as a good measure for the presence of nonlinearity in a time series. It has also been described as a measure of "success" or environmental fitness. I like it because acceleration gives you a quantification of the strength or magnitude of the force behind the first derivative or slope.

Comment: The remarks about acceleration, Hessian, greeks, and the exponential are somewhat telegraphic. No matter how I try to interpret and apply them to this context, they don't seem to match my experience with them. I suspect you may be referring to several mathematically related concepts that share a name but have quite different meanings than suggested here. For instance, exactly which of the greeks are you identifying with "acceleration"? Indeed, how does your definition of acceleration relate at all to sensitivities in the prices of financial derivatives?

Comment: @whuber  "Telegraphic?" I've been using these terms interchangeably for a long time and you're the first person to bridle at them. This doesn't mean you're wrong and, therefore, I'm right. But in terms of my own, personal "crowdsourcing," I find your persistent challenges a tad off -- I think you're fishing around for something. Acceleration or momentum, the rate of change in the rate of change, has embedded in it many other attributes within a time series – e.g., mass/force - which can be translated into many disciplines. Among the greeks, it corresponds to gamma. Hessian is Gallant's term.

Comment: Mathematically, acceleration and gamma are second derivatives--but there all connection with the context of this thread ends. Gamma is the second derivative of the value of a *derivative* on an asset with respect to its price. (Those are distinct uses of "derivative," btw.)  Acceleration is the second derivative of a function with respect to time. I believe you might privately be understanding these terms correctly, but that is not at all apparent in this post because it is just too terse: it lends itself to too many misinterpretations. I'm "fishing" for clarification and explanation.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments. I believe that what I'm seeking to quantify is not something that is a well know calculation in statistics circles. I thought maybe it was but I guess not.

Comment: @bobl  I will confess to still being a bit confused as to your original question. Quite honestly and in spite of all of the divagating opinions expressed on this thread, I am an expert at trends analysis. Please review this document and see if there isn't something that resonates with what you're trying to estimate. If your specific concerns still aren't addressed, I would like to propose taking this offline. I'm sure I can help answer your query, just not within the confines of this site  http://nymetro.chapter.informs.org/prac_cor_pubs/04-2015%20Thomas%20Ball_In%20Medias%20Res.pdf

Comment: Hi Mike, the goal of my original question was to learn the proper way to answer the question "does time series A trend better than time series B" where I used the time series of stocks Google and IBM as an example. From an investment standpoint it would likely be better to trade instruments which trend better than others. My definition of a better trend is one where there are more long periods of up or down movement in one time series versus another hence my idea of counting changes in direction of a certain % and the one with fewest changes over time therefore trends better. Thanks.