# Variance estimation of GLM coefficients

Tags: generalized-linear-model, covariance-matrix, hessian

I'm having trouble understanding the relationship between the variance of the GLM coefficients and the estimated observed Hessian. In the textbook I'm using it's stated "An obvious and suitable choice is based on the estimated observed Hessian". Which would mean:

$$
Var-cov(\beta)=E[\bigtriangledown \bigtriangledown^T l(\beta)]
$$

Can someone explain to me, why this is so? Or refer me to some relevant literature, which proves this relationship?

Comment: Welcome to CV. This question isn't clear, at least to me. Your matrix decomposition seems correct since it describes the Hessian as the matrix of second derivatives or "the rates of change in the rates of change." As such and as Ron Gallant describes it in his late 80s book *Nonlinear Statistical Models*, it is both an expression of the acceleration or momentum in the slopes as well as a statement of any inherent nonlinearities. What isn't clear about this?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the reply. To be more specific, I'd like to have a formal explanation, why the following equation holds:

$$
Var[\beta_i]=E[\bigtriangledown \bigtriangledown^T l(\beta)]_{ii},
$$

for $i=1,...,m$, where $m$ is the number of parameters.

Comment: It is unclear what the notation refers to.  It seems like a corrupted version of a standard result in likelihood theory, wherein "$Var-cov$" refers to the variance, "$\beta$" really means an *estimator* of a parameter vector (not the parameter itself), "$l$" is the *negative log* likelihood, the right hand side should be inverted (as a matrix), and the final "$\beta$" does refer to the parameters.  If these guesses are correct, then you are asking about the "minimum variance bound" or "Fisher Information," as described in any account of maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: @DJohnson As we discussed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/157245/919, that characterization of the expectation of the Hessian of the negative log likelihood is opaque and requires imaginative parsing to be understood in any manner that is pertinent and correct in this setting.

Comment: Yes I'm asking about the Fisher information. So the Fisher information is the negative Hessian if I'm not mistaken? But I cannot figure out, or find for that matter, why the following equation in MLE holds

$$
Var(\hat{\theta}_{ML})=[I[\hat{\theta}_{ML}]]^{-1}
$$

Comment: @whuber    Not being theoretically trained, I still like Gallant's description.

Comment: It is fine insofar as it goes, but it doesn't seem to help in this context.  Taking the expectation compels us to think through the interpretation more carefully, because the resulting expression is no longer really an "acceleration." And *of course* there are "inherent nonlinearities": this is a log likelihood we're talking about; except in trivial situations, it *must* be nonlinear!